# "No debuggable process" is shown in Android Studio Profiler

Tags: android, android-studio, profiler, android-profiler

When I try to use profiler in Android Studio, I am able to see my connected device but I am getting "No debuggable process" in the Profiler. Can someone please help me why i am getting "No debuggable process".

Comment: Your build variant is not debuggable, usually in AS a project comes with debug and release variants

Answer (score 4):

You can try any/all of the following:

1. Invalidating cache and restarting your `Android Studio`: To do this, from the menu bar select `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart`
2. Restart your phone
3. Disable and enable USB debugging
4. Restart your computer

You can also check if your app is marked as debuggable in `build.gradle`. To do this, just go to your app-level `build.gradle` file, and under `buildTypes` check if the `debuggable` property is set to false, if yes change it to true. Something like:

```
buildTypes{
    release {
        debuggable false
    }

    debug {
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to do the same you can also do it the old way by adding the following line to your `Manifest` file under the `Application` tag:

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

This should fix it.

Comment: Thank a lot, it saved a day of my life!
Running the File > Invalidate Caches / Restart solved my problem

Comment: Glad it helped :) an upvote goes a long way! would be appreciated and would motivate me to post more such answers. I hope the OP is also kind enough to mark it as accepted answer if it helped.