# How run android APK on Android Profiler?

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, android-profiler

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/deploy-test/profiling) to run an apk on Android Profiler but it doen't work to me. I did all the step one by one. I couldn't do the number *8: "Go to Project Settings> Modules, select the application -Signed node and click  (No SDK)"* because the *"No SDK"* option doesn't exist

[image]

Any way, on the step *9* I configured my Module SDK on *"Android API 25 Platform (java version 1.8.0_242)"*

Finally when I tried to run the apk, it sais *Operation succeeded* but it didn't show the memory usage or the CPU usage... so the step *14* does't do anything

[image]

**What could I do? What I am doing wrong?**

I already checked the "*Enable advancement profiling for older devices*"

[image]

Comment: I did a test,but I couldn't reproduce this problem. Have you deployed your app to a device?

Comment: yes, I tried both, on a device and virtually but nothing works. Any idea why?

Comment: I finally got the answer on this post
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540136/no-debuggable-process-is-shown-in-android-studio-profiler)

Comment: Congrats, and thanks for sharing your answer.  Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question is resolved based on your comments. But just to clarify, if you click the "+" sign on the Profiler tool window, you should be able to attach the profiler to any debuggable app that's running.

The checkbox of "Enable advancement profiling for older devices" shouldn't matter if the device is at Android Oreo or newer.